# ZeroClipboard issue

Tags: javascript, html, zeroclipboard

I am trying to copy the link of current page using ZeroClipboard and I don't know what to do further.
This is my code until now. How can I copy the link?

```js
function copyLink() {
  document.getElementById("copy").value += window.location.href;
  var link = document.getElementById("copy").value;
  var client = new ZeroClipboard();
  client.setText(link);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.2.0/ZeroClipboard.Core.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Copy</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id="copyBtn" onclick="copyLink()">Copy link</button>
    <textarea id="copy" style="display: none;"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks !

Comment: its not really clear what you want to do or what is the problem

Comment: I want to copy the link of  current page to clipboard using ZeroClipboard.

Comment: The function setText is from ZeroClipboard.js.